# Leaflet coordinate mapping wrong with OpenStreetMap when switching to EPSG 4326

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet

I'm trying to use leaflet to add an equi-rectanglular map layer on a scatterplot of latitude and longitude points.  When I create a tile layer with OpenStreet map and option 'crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326', I get two errors: first of all the mapping transformation is wrong (for the tiles I get), and I get tile loading errors like ("GET http://b.tile.osm.org/2/7/0.png 404 (Not Found)".

Removing the crs option to go back to the default mapping fixes both of these.  Is there some additional setting or transformation that I am missing?

Code snippet:

```
this.mapObj = new L.Map( plotElementIDinDOM, {
            zoomControl: false,
            dragging: false,
            touchZoom: false,
            scrollWheelZoom: false,
            doubleClickZoom: false,
            tap: false,
            crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326 // L.CRS.EPSG3857 (default)
        } );
var OSM2 = L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        } );
OSM2.addTo( this.mapObj );
this.mapObj.fitWorld();
```

I am trying to map points with:

```
this.mapObj.latLngToContainerPoint( latLngCoords );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use tiles already in the EPSG:4326 projection. Leaflet will not reproject raster tiles.