# Drawing on Leaflet map give incorrect coordinate

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, leaflet-draw

I am using Leaflet and OpenLayers. When I draw a bounding box I am getting the correct lat and lon if I use OpenStreetMap tilelayer.  When I switch to using EarthData tilelayer the bounding box is incorrect. [Map](https://jsfiddle.net/qms83p7a/2/)

Using this layer bring incorrect bounding box

```
 L.tileLayer('//gibs-{s}.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_TrueColor/default/'+tile_date+'/EPSG4326_250m/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg
```

gives correct bounding box.

```
 L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

Comment: Well, you seem to be using EPSG:4326 tiles in a EPSG:4857 map, so I'd say "learn about map projections"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaflet coordinate mapping wrong with OpenStreetMap when switching to EPSG 4326](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238801/leaflet-coordinate-mapping-wrong-with-openstreetmap-when-switching-to-epsg-4326)

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code **in the body of the question**, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Question talks about bounding box, but there is no such code above. Please edit your question and add all relevant existing code.

Comment: @IvanSanchez i will look into map projections and look at the link.  TomazicM I didn't know what code to post.  I posted the link to the map and explained the error.  Maybe I wasn't clear.

Comment: @newdeveloper re: how much code to show, do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking in general, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in particular

Comment: I will look into changing projections.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help.  I changed the tileLayer to use the default projection for leaflet `//gibs-{s}.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg3857/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_TrueColor/default/'+tile_date+'/EPSG3857_250m/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg`